# Unity3D iOS - scene takes much longer to load on iPhone 6s+

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, unity-game-engine

I've noticed that on the 6S+ the splash screen lasts longer and the scene starts before the splash screen ends. On the others, it went away quite fast.

I've tested on 4, 5, iPad2 and 6S+. Surprisingly, the 6s plus takes the longest to load. I'm using these settings.

[image: Other Settings tab]

(*)I'm using OpenGLES2 as I've heard it's faster than Metal. Having tried Metal too, I haven't seen any considerable performance improvements on the 6s+. I'll stick to it for now, unless I see any considerable difference.

Comment: OpenGL ES is not faster than Metal. Apple developed Metal, because OpenGL ES architecture is slow.

Comment: I stand corrected. However, there is no noticeable difference between the two in my project.

Comment: Anyway back to your question, what Unity Version are you using? Does this issue also happen, if you create a new test project or is it specific to your game?

Comment: I'm using Unity version 5.4.1f1 personal. It's happened to me on another game as well, however it didn't have much impact on the game flow because of the design of it. I've also seen many people complaining about the scene starting before the splash screen disappears.

Comment: you could try to test different Splash Image configurations in the Player Settings, to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Same behaviour, unfortunately